# Missing menu in Kate

Tags: kate

It's a rather simple problem, but I can't find the solution:

The menu bar in Kate (File, Edit, ...) has disappeared, and I tried looking up in the `katerc` file. How can I restore it?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Had the same problem... and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> also solved it for me. I never actively hide my menus, so arriving at this solution was not intuitive. No idea what (bug?) caused the sudden disappearance of the menu.

Comment: setting a keyboard shortcut to something like that is TOO WEIRD. Quickly after reading this answer, I deleted this shortcut.

Comment: Thank you. It is so incredibly stupid, who invent things like that? Tried Kate instead of gedit (because it has degraded to h***) and first thing: bang!, the toolbar is gone, and the solution is a counter intuitive shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

Came across this same bug this week. Unfortunately I had [Ctrl] + [M] mapped to something else. My solution was to find the file .katerc (in ~/.config on my Kubuntu machine), and invoked (courtesy of http://askubuntu.com/a/1274762/1002900)

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/MenuBar=Disabled/MenuBar=Enabled/g' {} \;
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/Show Menu Bar=false/Show Menu Bar=true/g' {} \;
```

to replace

`MenuBar=Disabled` and `Show Menu Bar=false`

with

`MenuBar=Enabled` and `Show Menu Bar=true`

I closed all my open kate windows, restarted, and my menu bar was back.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by:

- looking for `katerc` with `find * | grep katerc`, and deleted it
- `sudo apt purge kate`
- `sudo apt install kate`

Comment: This helped me https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=109594 - simple CTRL-M fixed my problem :)

Comment: Now I feel stupid. :D

Answer (score 2):

Three things are required to get your menus back under the title bar.

1. cd into your .config folder and execute:

   ```
   find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/MenuBar=Disabled/MenuBar=Enabled/g' {} \;
   ```
2. In KDE settings > Window management > Menu tab > remove burger applications menu from title bar in both active and inactive windows
3. In KDE settings > Startup > Services > disable the menu daemon

Plus if you want your top menus in kate, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> twice.